# Cloudflare configuration with Heroku and Amazon S3

Tags: caching, heroku, amazon-s3, cloudflare

I'm new in this, and I'm trying to figure out what's the proper solution. I've got website that is mostly serving a little text content and mostly images. Thus I'd like to use cloudflare for caching.

Hosting for my application is Heroku. I know that Heroku doesn't provide storage for static data like images, that's why it's required to use Amazon S3.

For now I'd like to use free cloudflare account(s). Please verify if my thinking is correct.

CloudFlare account1 -> caching for www.mysite.com (main domain for my app) which would cache css,js, and whatever is static on the website

CloudFlare account2 -> caching for smthsmth.myaccountname.s3.amazon.com (caching for images so that I don't have to pay too much to amazon for transfering my images)

Or it should be done in some other manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you clarify why you need 2 different CloudFlare accounts? I don't follow there. We have details here: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168926-How-do-I-use-CloudFlare-with-Amazon-s-S3-Service-   about how to use CloudFlare in front of your Amazon S3 bucket to save bandwidth and requests (and $$).

Comment: Hi. That was my guess. Because I'm assuming that 1 free cloudflare account is good for serving 1 domain. And since I've got 2 domains that I want to cache (mydomain.com and amazon s3 service) ... I'm asking what's the best apporach to that issue.

Comment: You can add as many domains as you'd like in a single CloudFlare account (up to 2,500 domains). I would recommend opening a support ticket with our support team directly and they can discuss specifics about your account and how to setup the domains when you have them in your account.